# How to sort an array of objects using their object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an array of objects with properties and I wanted to sort the objects by a specific property, how would I be able to do this? For example, let's say that I had a bunch of `news` objects each with a `date` property.

How would I be able to sort each of the objects in javascript by date?

Comment: This has been asked many, many times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your array is arr:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return ( a.date < b.date ? -1 : (a.date > b.date ? 1 : 0 ) );
});
```

Comment: sorry do you mean `date` instead of `data`?

Comment: are these outer parenthesis really needed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your own function to `.sort()`, something like this:

```
someArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.date < b.date)
    return -1;
  else if (a.date > b.date)
    return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

Your function just needs to be able to compare any two given objects and return negative or positive depending on which comes first or zero if they're equal. The `.sort()` function will take care of the rest.

This means you can sort on whatever property of the object you like, and even (optionally) introduce a secondary sort for cases where the first property is equal. You can also control ascending versus descending just by negating your return values.

Comment: Oops, probably should pay more attention to that banner at the top telling me another answer was posted. Oh well, I shall defiantly leave my answer up too since I gave a brief explanation along with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to the Array's sort method:

```
// Sample data
var newsArray = [
   {date: '2010/8/12'},
   {date: '2012/8/10'},
   {date: '2011/8/19'}
 ];

// Sorting function
function sortNewsArray(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
    }
  );
}
```

Provided the date strings can be converted to dates that simply. If not, just reformat so that they can, either in the data or the sort function.

Original order:

1. 2010/8/12
2. 2012/8/10
3. 2011/8/19

Sorted order:

1. 2010/8/12
2. 2011/8/19
3. 2012/8/10